# Issue with AJAX requests with in browser

Tags: jquery, error-handling, cross-browser, jsonp

I am implementing some AJAX requests to my server. The request type and params are exactly same in two cases but the response type coming from the server is different.

**CASE 1** :

This is implementation in Titanium using titanium network http client.

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function() {
        alert('sucess');
    },
    onerror : function(e) {
         alert('error');
    },
    timeout : 5000
});
var main_url = "http://localhost:3000/shops/560/login.json?api_token=some_token&customer[phone_number]=9988776655&customer[pin]=9876";
xhr.open('GET', main_url);
xhr.send();
```

which returns the response perfectly and seems working for me.

**CASE 2** :

This is implementation in local file using JQuery AJAX method.

```
var main_url = "http://localhost:3000/shops/560/login.json?api_token=some_token&customer[phone_number]=9988776655&customer[pin]=9876";

       $.ajax({
        url: main_url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status, xmlstatus) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(data, status, xmlstatus){
            if (t === "timeout") {
                alert("timeout");
            } else {
                alert("some error");
            }
        }
     });
```

But due to **CROSS DOMAIN policy** in **browsers** it returns

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/shops/560/login.json?api_token=some_token&customer[phone_number]=9988776655&customer[pin]=9876. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So, to avoid this I added another paramater

```
 &callback = ?
```

But still it returns

```
 alert('some error');
```

Not able to figure out where the stuff is going wrong.
When URL, parameters, type everything is same.

**---------------EDIT-------------**

Digging down iniside gives me respone :

```
 console.log(data) => parsererror
```

and

```
 console.log(xmlstatus) => jQuery164023596301255747676_1335786441349 was not called
```

Comment: Try making the url relative: `url: "/shops/560/login.json?api_token=some_token&customer[phone_number]=9988776655&customer[pin]=9876"`. I've seen instances where jQuery thinks it's querying an external server due to a port being specified.

Comment: `dataType: "json",` should be `dataType: "jsonp",`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist sorry that doesnt work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I cant make the URL that relative. I need to add the address of the server because I am making request from local file and not some html coming from the server. I am trying to make a cross domain request.

Comment: "some error" ? You don't have a better error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your server isn't answering with jsonp but simply with json.

A JSONP answer is like this :

```
callback(someJson)
```

Where callback is the name of the callback you provided or one automatically provided by jquery. You cannot simply call in JSONP a server that was made for JSON queries.

Here's a sample (a little complex, it's real code, but maybe you'll filter what's not related to your problem):

client : https://github.com/Canop/braldop/blob/master/chrome/braldop/inext_com.js

server : https://github.com/Canop/braldop/blob/master/go/src/braldopserver/BraldopServer.go

Comment: it was an error at server end wand was not responding back with callback to me :)

Answer (score 0):

As you're speaking of "local file", be careful that you cannot do a lot in ajax if you're loading your file with protocol file://. You need to use http:// even if the server is localhost.

Comment: @even after running on localhost the result seems to be unaffected and the error is same as updated above

Comment: Ok. I've seen your error message. So the problem isn't related to the used protocol.

Comment: what is the work around for it ?? I read a number of blogs and methods but none of them is working.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Are you looking for explanation on jsonp ?